# HTML 5 video not rendering on Android devices

Tags: android, ios, html, reactjs, google-chrome

I am trying to render out a full page background video.

The following code works on Chrome, Safari and Firefox for Desktop and on Safari and Chrome for iOS 11.

However this code is not working on any Android device. What is wrong here?

Code:-

```
<video 
    muted 
    ref={(video) => { this.videoPlayer = video; }}
    className='video' 
    playsInline
    autoPlay 
    onLoadedData = {this.startPlaying}
    onPlaying = {this.startedPlaying}
    onEnded ={this.onEnd}
>
 <source src="/video/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

/*Functions*/

onEnd = () => {
    console.log('ended');
    this.setState({
        showTimer: true
    });
}

startedPlaying = () => {
    console.log('started');
    this.setState({
        videoLoaded: true
    });
}

startPlaying = () => {
    console.log('loaded');
    this.videoPlayer.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try specifying the video source using the `src` attribute on the video element itself

Comment: i advice that you go slowly by removing all event handlers, mute attributes, and test. also specify the controls attribute to check as well.